# Инициализация в фреймворк Yii.

Tags: ооп, инициализация, php, yii, фреймворк

Не судите строго только начинаю осваивать ООП, поэтому прошу помочь разобраться в одной строке кода фреймворка Yii:
Это самое начало. фаил / index.php

```
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

Начну рассуждение по порядку. Вызывается статический методы "createWebApplication" класса "Yii" и передается переменная "$config". Но что означает эта часть "->run()"? Этот класс "Yii" расширяет "YiiBase", но в нем нет метода "run()". И, вообще, разве может быть метод у статического метода? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В YiiBase есть метод:

```
public static function createWebApplication($config=null){
    return self::createApplication('CWebApplication',$config);
}
```

Смотрим дальше:

```
public static function createApplication($class,$config=null)
{
    return new $class($config);
}
```

Т.е. метод createApplication вернет экземпляр класса CWebApplication

Идем в папку с классом:

```
class CWebApplication extends CApplication{
   ...
}
```

Идем в CApplication

```
abstract class CApplication extends CModule
{
   ...
       /**
         * Runs the application.
         * This method loads static application components. Derived classes usually overrides this
         * method to do more application-specific tasks.
         * Remember to call the parent implementation so that static application components are loaded.
         */
        public function run()
        {
              ...
            }
}
```

Вот этот то run и вызывается.

Answer (score 0):

`Yii::createWebApplication()` возвращает объект класса `CWebApplication`, унаследованного от `CApplication`, у которого методы `run()` есть.